# get most active users in a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get the most active users in a facebook page for a certain time period?
Is is possible to do it with the graph api?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way but you could pull down all posts via the Graph API and loop through the posts, comments, and likes and make your own ranking algorithm from that data.